# Is it possible to set HTTPS and Self-Signed Certificates in AspNetCore 3.1 server on raspberry pi with Win 10 iot?

Tags: ssl, windowsiot, aspnetcore-environment

Is it possible to set HTTPS and Self-Signed Certificates in AspNetCore 3.1 server on raspberry pi with Win 10 iot? I found only some solutions for linux and nginx https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/04/17/hosting-an-asp-net-core-2-application-on-a-raspberry-pi/, but no way for windows iot.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set HTTPS and Self-Signed Certificates in AspNetCore 3.1 server on Raspberry Pi. You can use [Import-PfxCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/import-pfxcertificate?view=win10-ps) or [Import-Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/import-certificate?view=win10-ps) to import your certificate. And then use HTTPS in the Asp.Net Core. Hope this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/) is helpful for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, example from the referenced blog is only AspNetCore 2.0. It does not work for raspberry pi. I can load certificate from pfx file, but I cannot access Kestrell Web Server on raspberry. I think some connect configuration is wrong. Same for all samples from https://learn.microsoft.com/ Again, i can not found any sample for   AspNetCore 3.1 server on Raspberry Pi with HTTPS.